# Multiple deletes from referencing tables take a long time when executed within the same transaction

Tags: postgresql

I am seeing some surprising (to me) behaviour when executing multiple `DELETE` statements within the same transaction on Postgres (15.3)

This can be seen easily with 2 tables: `table1` & `table2` where `table2` has a column that references `table1` as a foreign key.
`table1` has 60k rows and `table2` has 300k rows.

When the two `DELETE` statements are executed in separate transactions they complete effectively instantly.

```
DELETE FROM table2;
DELETE FROM table1;
```

However the second delete takes a long time to complete when executing them within the same transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM table2;
DELETE FROM table1;
COMMIT;
```

With timing enabled in `psql`:

```
DELETE 60000
Time: 212459.221 ms (03:32.459)
```

The second delete is doing a seq scan of `table2` for each row of `table1` as expected but it behaves as if the 300k rows are still there. Adding an index on to the referencing column in `table2` solves the issue, again as expected as the seq scan is avoided.

My questions is really why isn't the second `DELETE` aware that `table1` is empty at the point of execution. Is it able to 'see' the uncommitted deletes somehow (Specific behaviour of the MVCC perhaps) even though they aren't visible for SELECT and replacement values for the PK can be inserted.

Is this behaviour explained in the PostgreSQL documentation anywhere - I've searched but have been unable to find anything.

Comment: The statistics are not up to date anymore. And since the transaction hasn't been committed, auto analyze wouldn't see the changes anyway. This also proves that the real issue is the missing index.

Comment: Is it possible you want [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html) rather than DELETE?

Comment: @O.Jones a `TRUNCATE CASCADE` would work here, as would adding the index or running the deletes in separate transactions. I'm more interested in the underlying reason for the exhibited behaviour when using DELETE.

Comment: What is the FOREIGN KEY ON DELETE definition?

Comment: As @FrankHeikens stated, the fundamental issue is the lack of an index on the referencing column. Without that index, the sequential scan of `table2` is needed to ensure that referential integrity is maintained. Even though those rows have been deleted, their content is still present in storage, which affects scan time.

Comment: Thanks FrankHeikens and JohnH. That makes sense, do you know if this behaviour is mentioned in the PostgreSQL documentation anywhere?

Comment: [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html): Section *REFERENCES reftable  ... If the referenced column(s) are changed frequently, it might be wise to add an index to the referencing column(s) so that referential actions associated with the foreign key constraint can be performed more efficiently.*